# Determing sequence from its Dirichlet series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, dirichlet-series

Suppose I know the Dirchlet series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(3s)},$$ where $\zeta(s)$ is the usual Riemann zeta function.

My question is - is there a way to determine $f(n)$ from this information? If so, how?

Comment: Check out [Dirichlet series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Formal_Dirichlet_series) and  [Dirichlet convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution)

Comment: @Sasha Yes, I've checked these two pages before asking but somehow I am lacking the intuition to apply these ideas. Hence, do you mind elaborating a bit more please?

Comment: Hint: Use the Euler product for $\zeta(s)$.  (I'm assuming $f$ is multiplicative.)

Comment: @SpamIAm - It isn't necessary to assume that $f$ is multiplicative.  Given the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_nn^{-s}$ associated with the Euler product of $\zeta(s) \zeta(3s)^{-1}$, it is identical to the Dirichlet series of $f$, which will imply that $f(n) = a_n$ for each $n$.  Its a sort of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma analogue for Dirichlet series, see for example Tenenbaum's book II.1.

Comment: @smangerel Okay, so $f(n) = a_n$ for all $n$.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^s} & = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(3s)}\\
& = \prod_p \frac{1 - p^{-3s}}{1 - p^{-s}} &&\text{by the Euler product for $\zeta$ where the $p$s are all primes}\\
& = \prod_p \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^s} + \frac{1}{p^{2s}} \right) &&\text{by the identity $ 1 - x^3 = (1 - x)(1 + x + x^2)$}
\end{align}
Comparing with the [Euler product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Definition), we see that $f$ is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) and that
$$f(p^\alpha) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $\alpha = 1$ or $2$,} \\
0 & \text{if $\alpha = 3, 4, 5, \ldots$.}
\end{cases}$$

Because [a multiplicative function is completely determined by its values at the powers of prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function#Properties), we can restate the function as
$$f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if 1 is the largest cube that divides $n$,} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

The Dirichlet series for $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(3s)$ both converge absolutely for $s > 1$, so that definition of $f(n)$ is the only answer when $s > 1$ (see Theorem 4.8 at http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/ant/main4.pdf).

Comment: (The theorem 4.8 is simply that if $H(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty h(n) n^{-s}$ converges then as $\Re(s) \to \infty$ : $H(s) \sim h_m m^{-s}$ where $h(m)$ is the first non-zero coef, so we can recover uniquely $h(m)$ from its Dirichlet series)